# How to call new methods from a class which implements interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

How to call a new method which is implemented in the concrete class of an interface
I am using structure map IOC container.

```
public interface ICompanyRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Company> GetAll();
    Company Get(int id);
    Company Add(Company item);
    bool Update(Company item);
    bool Delete(int id);
}

public class CompanyRepository: ICompanyRepository
{
   // Provide implementation for all interface  methods

//Class CompanyRepository will also have the new method called DisplayLog
    public void DisplayLog()
    {
        //To do
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement DI using structure map in my Customer controller class
how can I tell the that I need methods ofcompany2 to be called?

```
_.Scan(x =>
     {
        x.TheCallingAssembly();

        x.AddAllTypesOf<ICompanyRepository>();

        // or

    });
```

My code:

```
private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository)
{
    customerRepository = CustomerRepository;
}

// GET: Customer  
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var customers = customerRepository.DisplayLog()
   //Here i need to call CompanyRepository class methods DisplayLog()  how can i call it here ?

   // method DisplayLog() is not be shown here 
    return View(customers);
}
```

Comment: The reason you're using an interface and DI is that you don't call the specific implementation, but call the interface as your code already does. If you really want to call the CompanyRepository methods, create a hard coupling instead and don't use DI.

Comment: but i have heard that we can achieve this using DI also

Comment: add void DisplayLog() to your interface?

Comment: The point of DI is to remove such hard coupling. Why do you want to call CompanyRepository class methods rather than using the interface?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Also what is `company2` in `i need methods ofcompany2 to be called`? You can start with brushing up your knowledge of interfaces and DI. And also of how to use structure map.

Comment: i have edited the question  company2  is nothing but  CompanyRepository  class

Comment: if you want to display log after some actions add, delete etc. just rise the method in an implementation of these methods.

Comment: I was given a Question in an interview to get this done using DI and  they told it can be done so i am trying from past 3 hours how to achieve this

Comment: There are three ways that I can see: **a)** downcast the instance of `customerRepository` and call the method;  **b)** Use concrete type in controller and change something in DI to make it work;  **c)** Create interface, put new method in it, add registration in DI and use that in controller instead of IRepository **d)** All that I've forgotten to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an Interface, you can only call what is defined in the Interface - Its a definition of a "common base" of all classes that implement it. Ask yourself: What should happen if the `ICompanyRepository` you get is of a type that does NOT implement `DisplayLog`?

That means: It is not possible to call anything else than the interface methods right away.

To call `DisplayLog` on `customerRepository` there are 3 ways:

- Add `DisplayLog()` to the Interface
- Cast the customerRepository to CompanyRepository. but this will cause an exception, if the customerRepository is of any other type than CompanyRepository
- Use a second interface

After all, I'm not quite sure if what you're doing is DI. In my understanding of DI it should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(ILogDisplay display)
{
    var customers = display.DisplayLog(customerRepository);
    return View(customers);
}
```

ILogDisplay is being a new Interface for a separate class to be injected

```
public interface ILogDisplay 
{
    public YourResultType DisplayLog(ICustomerRepository);
}
```

In this example you actually inject a dependency (the implementation of ILogDisplay) in your class.

Comment: Note: this Example is injecting to `CustomerController`. if you want to inject to `ICustomerRepository`, you can also add the Function `YourResultType DisplayLog(ILogDisplay display)` to `ICustomerRepository`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion how to implement it!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of questions to raise here:

1. Why does the repository know how to **display** a log?
2. What does `DisplayLog()` mean in the context of a CustomerRepository?
3. Why should the controller even care about what the repository is logging?
4. Why is DisplayLog assigning a variable called customers when its return type is clearly void?

Fundamentally, the behaviour of your repository should be unknown to your controller, this is the essence of the Inversion of Control principle. All it cares about is that given the explicit contract provided by the interface for a repository, a method call will return customers. Logging is a concern of the repository.

A fairly traditional setup, from a DI point of view us the following:

**ICompanyRepository:**

```
public interface ICompanyRepository() {
    IEnumerable<Company> GetAll();
    Company Get(int id);
    Company Add(Company item);
    bool Update(Company item);
    bool Delete(int id);
}
```

**CustomerRepository:**

```
public class CompanyRepository: ICompanyRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public CompanyRepository(ILogger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    // Provide implementation for all interface  methods

    public Company Get(int id) {

        var customers = this.randomCustomerSource.Get(id);
        this.logger.Info("Whatever you want to log here");
        return customers;
    }
}
```

**CustomerController:**

```
public class CustomerController {
    private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository)
    {
        customerRepository = CustomerRepository;
    }
    // GET: Customers
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var customers = customerRepository.GetAll()


        return View(customers);
    }
}
```

So the repository requests an `Ilogger`, the controller requests a `ICompanyRepository`, and will just call `GetAll()` and return the results. Usually there's a bit more involved but that's the very basic gist of a workflow for a controller that returns data.